# Node.js: making db variable available in controller files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am fairly new to node.js.

I am currently using lowdb for my database while I get the app started.

In the index.js file I have:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request');
var path = require('path');
var low = require('lowdb');
var db = low('db.json');
var routes = require('./routes');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use('/', routes);

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

Then in my routes file I have something like:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var account = require('./controllers/accounts.js');

router.post('/login', account.login);

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('home');
});

module.exports = router;
```

And finally in my account controller I have:

```
exports.login = function(req, res){
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
       ...
}
```

The routing to controller system works. However I need to access the lowdb object from all of my routed controller functions (and also possibly elsewhere).

If in app.js I set:

```
global.db = db;
```

Then it seems to work, but from what I have read, setting this globally isn't the ideal solution. What is the appropriate way to be able to access the db from the controller files without having to set the db connection in every single file.

Answer (score 1):

In your `index.js` file (application root) store the `lowdb` object in your `express` object :

```
var app = express();
var db = low('db.json');
app.db = db;
```

In your controller (`accounts.js`), access your database with `req.app.db` :

```
exports.login = function(req, res){
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var db = req.app.db;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can probably just setup and use the `db` directly in your routes file since you're not actually using the `db` in your main file. If it's that simple then I'd opt for doing that:

```
// routes file
var low = require('lowdb');
var db = low('db.json');
```

Alternatively, if you need to setup your `db` in the main file and pass it into the routes file and/or other modules, instead of exporting the router directly in the routes file, export a `function` which takes the `db` as input and returns the `router`. Then you can pass the `db` into the routes module when you `require` it.

```
// routes file
module.exports = function (db) {
  // router setup using the input `db`
  // ...
  return router;
}

// index.js
var low = require('lowdb');
var db = low('db.json');
var routes = require('./routes')(db);
```